# Proof that the product of locally integrable function $g$ with any test function is zero implies $g=0$ a.e

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, smooth-functions

How to prove that If for  $g\in L_{p}$  $p\in(1,2]$ and for all $\phi \in C_{0}^{\infty}$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g \phi d\mu =0  $  then $g=0$ a.e where $\mu $ is the Lebesgue measure.

I was thinking about introducing some $\eta_{n}$ which are tending to 1 as $n \to \infty $

Comment: This result is called **[DuBois-Reymond lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations)**, and you can find many proofs of it, even without the use of mollifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q=\frac p {p-1}$. A well known result, proved using Lusin's Theorem says that $C_0^{\infty}$ functions are dense in $L^{q}$. If $h \in L^{q}$ choose $\{h_n\} \subset C_0^{\infty}$ such that $\|h_n-h\|_q \to 0$. It then follows (by Holder's inequality) that $\int gh=\lim \int g h_n$. Hence $\int gh=0$ for all $h \in L^{q}$ and this implies $\int_a^{b}g(x)\, dx=0$ whenever $a<b$. This in turn implies $g=0$ almost everywhere.

Remark: $p\leq 2$ is not necessary.

Comment: Why does $\int gh=0$ for all $h$ imply $\int_{a}^{b} g=0$ ? Are you taking  $h=1$ Over the set $(a,b)$ and zero else ware?

Comment: @Monty Yes, that is my choice of $h$. Note that $h$ does belong to $L^{q}$.

Comment: and you use holder to get a bound for dominated convergence theorem ? Sorry i was not fully understanding.

Comment: @Monty No DCT: $|\int (gh_n-gh)| \leq ||g\|_p \|h_n-h\|_q \to 0$.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks.